# Can't require a module while using Mocha with Babel compiler

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, babeljs

I have two files: `test.js` that contains

```
var Buffer = require('./Buffer');
```

and `Buffer.js` with

```
this.foo
```

when I run them with `mocha test.js`, everything works fine, but running `mocha --compilers js:babel/register test.js` generates the following error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'foo' of undefined
at Object.<anonymous> (/path/Buffer.js:1:1)
at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
at normalLoader (/path/node_modules/babel/node_modules/babel-core/lib/babel/api/register/node.js:150:5)
at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/path/node_modules/babel/node_modules/babel-core/lib/babel/api/register/node.js:163:7)
at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
at require (module.js:384:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/path/parser_test.js:2:14)
at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
at normalLoader (/path/node_modules/babel/node_modules/babel-core/lib/babel/api/register/node.js:150:5)
at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/path/node_modules/babel/node_modules/babel-core/lib/babel/api/register/node.js:163:7)
at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
at require (module.js:384:17)
at /path/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:192:27
at Array.forEach (native)
at Mocha.loadFiles (/path/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:189:14)
at Mocha.run (/path/node_modules/mocha/lib/mocha.js:422:31)
at Object.<anonymous> (/path/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha:398:16)
at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
at startup (node.js:129:16)
at node.js:814:3
```

Why is it happening that `this` is undefined when I require a module? Please let me know if you need any additional information to reproduce the error.

I use babel 5.5.0 and mocha 2.2.5.

Comment: pls show us the whole code of your `Buffer.js` and `test.js`. Generally, to `require` a module you have to export it as a module with `module.exports = ???`.

Comment: @marcel, you can export anything from that module, it fails as soon as it encounters the line `this.foo`.

Comment: again: "pls show us the whole code of your Buffer.js and test.js."

Comment: Without the full module code of `Buffer.js`, or at least the surrounding parts to `this.foo`, it is difficult to diagnose and correctly respond to your question.

Comment: @MarkSimulacrum, my content of `Buffer.js` is the minimal example of a failing file. The issue appears when a property of `this` is accessed. It doesn't matter which property or what else is present in the file.

Comment: @shock_one What are you expecting `this` to be?

Comment: @MarkSimulacrum, global object, which it is without babel. https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Babel expects that the input it is given is an ES6/ES2015 module. In modules, top-level `this` is `undefined` by the specification.

`babel --blacklist strict script.js` will allow you to disable this behavior, but this is not according to the specification, so this probably isn't the best idea. You can use `global` instead to access the global object in `node`, as an alternative.

For more information, see the [documentation](https://babeljs.io/docs/faq/#why-is-this-being-remapped-to-undefined-).